# Thick-thin client

Tags: architecture, thin-client, thick-client

Good day, everyone!

I have a architectural question, what tools can I use when will develop and deploy a think client for ONE DESKTOP computer? My application must work in browser on one computer, DB must placed on same computer. If it possible, no application server (IIS, Apache, Node.js).

Comment: It sounds like the question is too broad, its better to provide some additional info about OS, languages etc.

Comment: To start it will work in Windows, but I think browsers are crossplatform, and HTML application will work for any OS. For example I can use Node.js+Html+Js, write some code in JS and HTML, for DB I can use MySQL or MongoDB, but it is too big application tools, or I can use just Html page with WebSQL. In general I need develop little applications, and I do not want use thick client.

Answer (score 0):

To make desktop application from HTML application, you'll need JS libraries that can call native OS API, something like [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi), [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) or appjs[3], that allows use native API, but they all work under node.js framework. Or you can try use browser API for access to OS functions, Firefox[4] and Chrome[5].

If you need to develop simple web application, try use HTML pages + JS + CSS + WebSQL or localStorage.

Here[6] you can learn more about HTML5.

3 - appjs.com/

4 - developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Using_the_Browser_API

5 - developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

6 - slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide